# python socket.getservbyport() Not returning the service

Tags: python, erp

Folks I am learning Python Socket, where I can't find a specific service result in a port Number.
 For example I'm using a ERP software called **'Tally.ERP9'** 
Where ODBC Server of Tally.erp9 is running in port 9000[image: Where ODBC server is Running in port 9000]

Here we can check the service is running in localhost at 9000
[image: Here We can see the service is running in localhost at 9000]

But when I try `socket.getservbyport(9000)` It didn't returned the service Name
May I know why this happens, and is there any way where I can check whether the service is running or not with the help of `socket`? please explain me why Socket is not returning the correct results here 
Thanks In advance!

Comment: Python's [`socket.getservbyport()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getservbyport) is a [thin wrapper](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/socketmodule.c#L4952) for the [C-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It does not check whether or not a service is running, it just consults the services database for a name mapped to a port. Apparently your service is not registered in the services database.

Comment: You mean that it would not show the service in the real time, in that case may I know how could I list all the services that actively running in real time environment. can you suggest me how can I do this with python and may I know how can I check the services databases you Mentioned earlier

Comment: Can't say for sure where the services db is on windows, perhaps `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\services`. It's just a file of name - port (- some other info) lines. I meant exactly that: it does not in any way check whether or not a service is running, bound to a port or anything. It just looks up names and ports from a DB.